# Sending a None back to the caller from an Actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a simple Actor that queries a database using ScalaQuery, which I've mocked for a test of a client using it.

What I want is for the (mock) Actor to reply with `Some(MyObject)` if the ID matches up, and `None` otherwise. However, I can't figure out how to make this work. Here's the code I have so far:

```
def receive = {
  case FetchSomething(someId) => {
    if (someId == 1234) self.channel ! someObject
    else self.channel ! None
  }
}
```

However, instead of returning `None` in the client code, it returns `Some(None)` - which, of course, confuses my client. How I want the client to work is something like this:

```
val object = persister !! FetchSomething(1337) match {
    case myObject: Some[MyObject] => myObject
    case _ => None
}
```

(of course, the above may just be wrong - instead of `Some`, it could be `Option`)

How can I achieve this? Perhaps more specific, how can I send a `None` back through self.channel so when matching it, it's `None` and not `Some(None)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fault is in the client, which misinterpret the reply, not following AKKA protocol. From [the Akka documentation](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/actors.html#send-and-receive-eventually) :

> The !! method returns an Option[Any] which will be either Some(result)
>   if returning successfully, or None if the call timed out.

So if reply is None, client  Some(None). If reply is Some(12) you get Some(Some(12)). If client receives None, it should not means the actor replied None, it means the actor did not reply.

This is **AKKA protocol**, and it means client should process reply with

```
case Some(answer) => process answer
case None => actor did not reply
```

Then if your actor happens to reply with an Option[Something], that is **your protocol**, which is another layer:

```
case Some(answer) => /* your protocol */ answer match { 
  case Some(actualValue) => reply had actualValue
  case None => None was the reply
}
case None => actor did not reply
```

Which of course, you can also write

```
case Some(Some(actualValue)) => 
case Some(None) => 
case None =>
```

---

A side note, do not match with `x: Some[A]` (do not give the type parameter when matching on a generic type). It does not work, it will not verify that you have a `Some[Something]`, but not that `Something` is `A` (see type erasure, the compiler gives a warning). You want to match with `case Some(x: A)` which gives you the content of the `Some` in `x`, what you normally want. If you actually want the `Some` rather than its content, `case s @ Some(x: A)` will bind `s` to the `Some` instance, `x` to its content. Use `_` instead of x if you are not interested in it.

If it is known that the type inside the option is `A`, then do not mention it, just write
`case Some(x)`, `case s: Some(_)`